# Confusion about Ascoli's formula

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, analytic-geometry

I'm trying to prove [Ascoli's formula](http://www.mat.unimi.it/users/libor/Funz2/ascoli.pdf):
$$\mathrm{dist}(x,\ker f)=\frac{|f(x)|}{\|f\|}$$
But I struggle, because I have problems believing it holds.

Let's supposer we're in a 3D space with functional

$f=(2\ 1\ 0)$,
$\ker f = \mathrm{span}\{(0\ 0\ 1)^T\}$,
$\|f\|=2$

Now let's suppose my point in space is $x=(0\ 1\ 0)^T$, $f(x)=1$.

Now according to the theorem:

$\mathrm{dist}(x,\ker f)=\frac{1}{2}$,

but $\mathrm{dist}(x,\ker f)=1$

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I didn't know this very interesting generalization of formulas that are used in more ordinary settings, as you have done in $\mathbb{R^3}$. See for example (http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Point-PlaneDistance.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The kernel of a (non-zero) linear functional always has codimension $1$, so in this case the kernel must have dimension $2$. In fact, we have
$$ \ker(f)=\mathrm{span}\{(1,-2,0)^T,(0,0,1)^T\} $$